# Add android target to visual studio for Mac

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-mac

I'm building over a non from scratch project, that a previous developer created in my office.
In a previous version of `Unity - Visual Studio for Mac` I generated some build for iOS, but now, with the newest version, I get this configuration:

[image]
Also, the configuration for `Android` is disabled.
[image]

How I can add `Android` as target for my project to generate an `apk` file?

**UPDATE 1**
`VS` Configuration.
[image]

**UPDATE 2 / BUILD CONFING**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the following link to setup unity to make `Android APK`:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html

You will need to download: the latest version of java, and the android sdk.
You will need to set the unity path to the sdk
You will need to download and set up the android ndk.

Sounds like a lot of work but its really a lot of waiting. the `Android SDK` can take some time depending on which versions you wish to support and how far back you go.

Once you have followed the guide above you will be able to change your project to android in the project settings menu.

Good luck!

For mac users with unity looking to set up android:

[Instructions for Mac](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/unity-developer-setting-up-your-mac-android-builds-surath-chatterji)

[image]

you should be able to select android here and then click switch platform...

Comment: I have both installed previously, also, the latest version of `Android Studio` installed before `VS Unity`. I verified the environment variable `PATH` and files and are all in the right location. What more can I check?

Comment: File-Build Settings      is it available as a platform there? if it is select it, then click Player settings to adjust version and package...

Comment: i added a link to my answer specifically for mac users. some configuration stuff, such as your `JAVA_HOME` path not being persistent and a few other things you can try.

Comment: I updated the question, all the configuartions are ok, but the options in `Tools` > `Android` is still disabled.

Comment: wow... yeah that is vexxing... it seems to be set up correctly... i see your run configurations are empty, have you tried making a new one? whats in your build configs? any option there? what about your player settings....

Comment: I updated the question with the `Build configuration`, but are basically empty.

Comment: try closing visual studio, and setting unity to android, then open your script through unity. it should reopen visual studio with the corrct settings if everything else is set right

Comment: Ok, I did it! But, the option `Run` and `Android` are still with appear enable. But the options to manage `Android SDK` is now enabled. 
Is this problem related with `Run configurations` ?

Comment: TBH, why your having this problem is now beyond me, lol. i can say i had a similar problem, and it had something to do with version conflicts in VS i had to redownload or update VS. unity has just said they will no longer do VS 2017 on mac just 2018 and up from now on, so if your unity is newer than your VS that might be causing it ... i assume you have made sure both were up to date though.  i would expect it to be build configurations, but it is possible. (my run button changes to "attach to Unity") when im using both together.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate! That is enough to continue by my side. Thanks!